# Function only declared, but still working

Tags: c++, c

I am having this function that is only declared and not defined anywhere. But still the program is working fine in C but not in C++. How is this possible.

```
void pzKasittelija(char *lid, char *lid2); // this function is only declared not defined anywhere
```

PS: I checked in all libs and header files, that function is not defined!!!

This is the error message I am getting with C++

> Error  2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(char *,char *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(...)'

Please have a look at these links. these are the files where the problem lies.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2hZqiBoBiNEcVFUTFJyZUZvY1U/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2hZqiBoBiNEZWl6VzR4bzFHWm8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you calling that function?

Comment: is the function gets called ever?

Comment: All logic says this can't be "working" in my definition of what working means.

Comment: ofcourse
xpar.cmd_handler = (pzKasittelija);

Comment: different compilers different rules.

Comment: how do you call this function?

Comment: Please describe in what way it doesn't "work" in C++. The word "not" doesn't provide much detail.

Comment: it looks like the place where you are calling this prototype is expecting a different signature.  Could you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing how you utilise it to raise that error?

Comment: It may be _compiling_ in C, but is it actually _working_?

Comment: Because a function prototype with an empty parameter list means different things in C and C++.

Comment: Take a look at [Error C2440](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx). It seems to be function prototype problem. Take a look at function pointer assigments, probably there are more restrictions in C++ compiler, but it is a long shot without more code do analyze.

Comment: @molbdnilo: can you elaborate on that.

Comment: In C++, `void f()` takes *no* parameters and is equivalent to `void f(void)`; in C, `void f()` can take *any* parameters and is different from `void f(void)`, but is compatible with `void f(char*, char*)`.

Comment: Not clear what really your situation is. The only information that you provided after being asked is that you assign the function pointer somewhere, but not if the function is really called (I guess not) and if the whole code that uses that function pointer is perhaps optimized out. Voting to close this question, because it is not clear at all.

Comment: please post a sample of code we can look at, I think this will be a simple case when we can see what is actually happening.

Comment: @GMasucci: i have posted the sample code. please have a look at it.

Comment: I cant locate the files, says they are unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Since this is only a [function prototype](http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html) it just informs the compiler that a function as such would be used in the code. By using a function prototype you can define the functions after the code for their call is made.

When you include a header , you include the prototypes of several functions in that `.h` file and the compiler doesn't expect you to call all of them

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not have a compilation error because it is a void function, so all it does is nothing. If you the program behaves as expected, that means that you can safely erase the function.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is written for the bcc32 and VC++ C compilers, and as such may not compile exactly the same under C++ since C++ has much stricter rules about converting types. C will just let it happen, C++ wants to you to make it explicit.